# How do I pass an ArrayList of custom type to AsyncTask's doInBackground?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I've looked for answers here already and can find some similar ones but they're not quite what I'm looking for.

So I need to pass an `ArrayList` of `CustomClass` to the `doInBackground` of my `AsyncTask`. The list is sent as a Varags but when I try to get my `ArrayList` out in `doInBackground()`, it's empty!

This is my class:

```
  private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<CustomoClass>, Void, Void>{
    ...
    @Override
    protected final Void doInBackground(ArrayList<CustomClass>... arrayLists) {
        
        // Pull out arrayList and log it's contents to see what's there
        ArrayList<CustomClass> arrayList = arrayLists[0];
        Log.i("TEST_SHOP", "doInBackground() arrayList: " + arrayList.toString());

        //Do Stuff Here
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it:

```
void deleteAsync(ArrayList<CustomClass> itemArrayList){
    Log.i("TEST_SHOP", "deleteAsync() itemArrayList: " + itemArrayList.toString());
    new MyAsyncTask(dao).execute(itemArrayList);
}
```

And this is the result I get in the log from `doInBackground`:

> I/TEST_SHOP: doInBackground() arrayList: []

When I log the contents of the `ArrayList` from `deleteAsync()` the contents are all there. I honestly don't know why this doesn't work. Any advice is well appreciated!

Comment: is the itemArrayList passed into deleteAsync modified/cleared from elsewhere? Try creating a new ArrayList in the deleteAsync(...) and passing that into the task.

Comment: @Madushan Oh my god yes I was modifying on the UI thread! Thanks :)